# How to decrypt all my personal files which is encrypted by window after window 10 reset?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, anti-virus, ransomware

All my personal files and excel files are encrypted by window when i reset window 10. Now i am not able to open my excel files. In all my files, the extension .geno is added in all the files (Mouse list.xlxs.geno ) and unreadable text are appear.

I got one text file(_readme.txt) in every folder. Inside _readme.txt file **(ATTENTION!

Don't worry, you can return all your files! All your files like photos, databases, documents and other important are encrypted with strongest encryption and unique key. The only method of recovering files is to purchase decrypt tool and unique key for you. This software will decrypt all your encrypted files. What guarantees you have? You can send one of your encrypted file from your PC and we decrypt it for free. But we can decrypt only 1 file for free. File must not contain valuable information. You can get and look video overview decrypt tool: https---- Price of private key and decrypt software is $980. Discount 50% available if you contact us first 72 hours, that's price for you is $490. Please note that you'll never restore your data without payment. Check your e-mail "Spam" or "Junk" folder if you don't get answer more than 6 hours.

To get this software you need write on our e-mail: mail.ch

Reserve e-mail address to contact us: airmail.cc

Your personal ID: )**

I am using window 10 Home

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You are a victim of ransomware.  You will have to restore your files from a backup.  Your files are permanently encrypted, and since you performed a Reset, there is no way to decrypt them.  **You should absolutely NOT pay the ransom for your files.**

Comment: Window reset causes this problem?

Comment: No, your computer is infected by ransomware, if you dont have uninfected backups of those files you have to pay the scumbags $$$ to decrypt them. Whatever you decide you need to do a Clean Install of W10 to get rid of the ransomware.